# How to create a Google Doc with fixed-size elements?

Tags: google-apps-script

So this is the situation: 
I have a Google Spreadsheet with an attached Google Apps Script.
Based on data in the spreadsheet I want to create a document that can be printed onto label stickers.  In other words, I have to create an m×n matrix of elements that are of a fixed size (w×h mm).  I'd much prefer to be able to do all operations in the web browser, and I can't really see why this should not be possible, but none of the options I have tried so far have resulted in a document where I have the necessary level of layout control:

- Creating a Spreadsheet where each cell contains the text for a label. 
  However, I can only set the cell height and width in pixels, not in
  millimetres, and on printing margins that I cannot control are added to the document.  (And, in order to limit the display
  of the cell contents in the vertical direction I have to do a strange
  workaround by merging my cell with the cell below it.  What’s with
  that?)
- Creating a Document with a table where each cell contains the
  text for a label.  In this case I can set the minimum height of a
  cell, but I cannot limit the maximum height.  If it were possible to detect the current height of a table cell, I could truncate strings that overflow the cell, but this information is not available. Alternatively, if I could modify the underlying HTML representation of the document I could modify the relevant attributes, but this is not possible either.
- Creating an HTML document
  with a table where each cell contains the text for a label.  In this
  case I can directly set the width and height of the cell and use the
  **overflow** attribute to restrict the contents to the given extents. 
  However, I cannot create an HTML file in my Docs area, so instead I tried to use a
  ModelessDialog to contain my table.  This sort of works in that in
  Firefox and Safari (though *not* in Google Chrome!) I can print out
  the table, but *only* the first page of it.  This is due to the body
  of the HTML automatically getting wrapped in a 
  **<div id="guest" style="height:100%; overflow: auto">**
  and I have not figured out a way of getting rid of this.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to achieve what I want?